# how to find the best city to meet people from across the globe?

Tags: air-travel, transit, planning, flight-search-engines

I have a group of friends who live across the globe in different cities. We're like a family, lived together for about 4-5 years in Tokyo. But people moved on to their next cities for work or education, adventure or closer to family.
We want to organize a meetup/reunion in 2024. Next year marks 10 years since we met.

Here are the residential cities of the people involved:

1. Mumbai
2. Bengaluru
3. New Delhi
4. Tokyo (2 people)
5. London
6. Dubai
7. San Francisco
8. Seattle

I want to find the best meeting point with convenient flight connectivity.

**Edit**: My definition of best is such that everyone travels about the same time or the total travel time is reduced by one person traveling farther, like finding the centroid of a polygon or centre of gravity of an object of mass. Can it be done within 12 hours for each of the participants? Wish the concorde was still flying.

I could think of 3 options:

1. London
2. Istanbul
3. Dubai

2 of them are cities where 1 of us lives (London & Dubai)
Istanbul is a city where 2 of us have been to and are familiar with but others haven't.

I tried using the [geomidpoint](https://geomidpoint.com) website. It shows Kazakhstan. But I checked both the capital Astana & the busiest airport Almaty, neither of them has great connectivity as per flightconnections.com . [image: Screenshot attached]

I am looking for suggestions to other alternative destinations besides the 3 I listed above. Perhaps, there is a major city with a great airport and airlines offering connectivity to most destinations (preferably direct but 1 international transit is fine).

Are there any tools that can help find possible destinations with connectivity from multiple origins?

If there are no such tools & alternate destinations suggestions, eager to have help deciding which one you'd recommend. As of now, London seems best to me.

I understand that DEL (141 destinations in 50 countries) & BOM (113 destinations in 37 countries) have better connectivity than BLR (88 destinations in 21 countries). so 1 domestic transit is also fine for people to allow them to fly together from either of the three cities.

We have lived in Tokyo & most of us have visited some or the other city (either NYC,SFO,SEA,LAS) in USA.

Hope to experience something new & refreshing, safe & do a bit of an adventure.
Therefore, there must be plenty to do at the destination such as day trips to countryside without crossing borders and visa hassles so that we can spend a week together.

All of us have Indian passports, have traveled across Japan & possess valid US B1/B2 visas if that helps.
It's okay for all or some of us to have to apply for a visa for one particular country such as UK to visit London.
It's okay if some of us visit a place again such as Istanbul.

Comment: I seem to recall @franck-dernoncourt posting something similar (I may be thinking of the wrong user) about an app or website that will determine the best destination for several travelers to meet from very different origins

Comment: @Midavalo yes, i checked https://meet.flights & https://tripmatch.org, but both are not working as of now.

Comment: The obvious place to meet would be Tokyo, are you explicitly excluding that as an option?

Comment: Is local language a factor? In addition to the cities you mentioned, other large hubs which may be relevant could include Singapore, other Gulf cities (Abu Dhabi, Doha…), possibly Bangkok, Kuala Lumpur or Hong Kong. If travel time is not an issue (in any case at least some of the participants will have to travel 12h+ anyway, is 20h+ acceptable?) then Sydney is a great option. But all in all, I don’t think there’s a “right” answer to this question, at least with the given criteria (or lack thereof)…

Comment: @jcaron sorry for lack of criteria, i edited the question now to clarify what best meeting point implies to me. local language is not a factor. i am curious to know options as clearly mentioned and tools to find them. Thank you for partially answering with BKK,KUL,HKG,SIN,AUH,DOH.

Comment: @lambshaanxy not excluding Tokyo or Japan, but since we know the city & the country, was more keen on considering new places that we might be willing to explore elsewhere.